# How to use MapJsonSubKey with json array

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using the oauth2 flow in an MVC application. I can be redirected to the provider to challenge the user and password and I can get access token to be used for the API call
once I made the API call I can retrieve the info but the response is a JSON that contains an array
how can I use the MapJsonSubKey to map the email from the below JSON?

```
{
    "ErrorList": null,
    "Status": 1,
    "UserDetailList": [
        {
            "Email": "pippo.pluto@xxx.com",
            "FirstName": "pippo",
            "LastName": "pluto",
            "PersonId": "pippo.pluto@xxx.com",
            "ProfilePhoto": 1,
            "ProfilePhotoPath": null,
            "Status": 100,
            "Title": null,
            "UpdatedDate": "/Date(1561120073327+0000)/",
            "UserGUID": "8f643f10-0559-4e34-972d-52f41a4b9fcc",
            "UserId": 20,
            "UserName": "ca9ba551-9347-45b3-a926-c9bf361252e0"
        }
    ]
}
```

if I use this code

```
 options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"Id");
 options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name");

 options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:infor:status", "Status");
 options.ClaimActions.MapJsonSubKey("urn:infor:uname", "UserDetailList[]", "Email");
```

and in the cshtml, i use this

```
 @User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:infor:uname")?.Value
```

i cannot see any value in the page

Comment: any news for this topic?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?